# For which $a$ and $b$ the function $\frac{ax+b}{a^2x+b^2}$ is increasing?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> For which $a$ and $b$ the function  $$\frac{ax+b}{a^2x+b^2}$$ is increasing?

I know that function is increasing if $x_1 > x_2 \implies f(x_1)>f(x_2)$ but how can I find $a$ and $b$ for which this statement will be true?

Comment: This would be straightforward to do with calculus (differentiate, set the derivative $> 0$, solve for $x$), but I assume from the tag that you're looking for a non-calculus answer?

Comment: It shouldnt be too hard with partial derivative calculus. Find the optimization points of the first partial derivative with respect to each a and b.

Comment: exactly, i know what you mean by that, and i would know how to do it by differentiation, but i want non-calculus solution

Comment: Non calculus - ok, its root is -b/a under certain conditions, and its limit is 1/a under certain conditions (when x tends to infinity). At 0 it is 1/b, so now you can work your way -- depends on 'a' and 'b'

Comment: Why do you want to avoid calculus? Is there a legit reason?  Not all problems are solvable using trivial algebraic techniques.  My best advice then is to use a CAS or graphical analysis.

Comment: Because, it is stated that i should not use calculus to solve this, i have to use different methods, i guess that the point of this example is to practice 'ordinary' algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divide both polynomials:

$$\frac{ax+b}{a^2x+b^2}=\frac{a}{a^2}\left(1+\frac{b/a-b^2/a^2}{x+b^2/a^2}\right)=\frac{a}{a^2}+\frac{{a/a^2(b/a-b^2/a^2)}}{x+{b^2/a^2}}$$

This is function $1/x$ scaled and moved. The scale is

$$k=\frac{a}{a^2}\left(\frac{b}{a}-\frac{b^2}{a^2}\right)$$

You know that $c/x$ is decreasing when $c>0$ and increasing when $c<0$. In your case $k<0$:

$$\frac{a}{a^2}\left(\frac{b}{a}-\frac{b^2}{a^2}\right)<0$$
$$a(ab-b^2)<0$$
$$a^2b-b^2a<0$$
$$a^2b<b^2a$$

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any calculus to solve this question: just us the canonical form of this homographic function:
$$\frac{ax+b}{a^2x+b^2}=\frac1a+ \frac {b(a-b)}a\frac1{a^2x+b^2}$$
Now on each interval that make up its domain, the function $\dfrac1{a^2x+b^2}$ is decreasing, hence the given function  is

- decreasing if $\;ab(a-b)>0$,
- increasing if $\;ab(a-b)<0$.

Here is a graphical representation of the discussion in an $(a,b)$-plane:

[image]